# Drupal - Get "Year" value from a "Date" Field

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-modules

I have a "Date" field named "X". I have another field "Y" that references a "Field" type.
I would like to get just the "Year" value from "X" into "Y".

I would prefer doing this using GUI instead of adding/modifying PHP code. Is there a module that can help accomplish this?

Both "X" and "Y" are in the same Content Type.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Simple question for assessment : Why do you need to replicate year part in another field ?

Comment: I am trying to create a view where pages are grouped by year.

Answer (score 1):

Within views module you can group by date without having to duplicate a datetime/timestamp field only to retrieve the year part. For you custom view :

- Under **format** title, use "fields" beside "show", select your prefer settings
- Under **Fields** title, select the date field you need to tune, Formatter as **default** and Date format as **Custom**. As Custom date format put **Y** (see here https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters). If desired field can be hidden from the view, up to you.
- Return under **format** title, format -> Settings : there you can choose your grouping field you just created, even if hidden.

This is out of the box but I advise you to play around with views settings, one at the time, to understand what changes what.

Views is very powerful.

Comment: Thanks!! This was helpful. 
What worked was adding the Date field twice and then grouping it by "Y" on one of the hidden Date fields.